# Find all links which contain array of items

Tags: jquery, arrays

I've searched for about an hour for this but could not find it. I'm trying to use jQuery to find and highlight an array of links on the page. What I originally had was:

```
$(table).find('a[href*="7000"], a[href*="7001"], a[href*="6020"], a[href*="6987"]').addClass('highlight');
```

Which is fine, until you have a *really* long list of links with different numbers to look for (which is what I'll have soon). Basically, I want to enter all the numbers in an array and use those. So I tried:

```
var $href = 'a[href*="';
var $numbs = ('7000', '7001', '6020', '6987');
var $end = '"]';
    $('.tripname').find($href + $numbs + $end).each(function() {
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
    });
```

But it didn't work. It only finds the last one, apparently.

Any thoughts on this are appreciated.

Comment: Use your debugger and look at what `$numbs` is equal to after you set it. You need to use square brackets to define an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array syntax is wrong. [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) are surrounded by square brackets.

After fixing that, you could make use of:

- [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to generate the selector for each number, and
- [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to combine them into a multiple selector

```js
const numbers = [7000, 7001, 6020, 6987];

const selector = numbers
  .map(n => `a[href*="${n}"]`)
  .join(',');

console.log(selector);
```

You can then use that selector with jQuery.

Comment: That's interesting. I'll have to remember this for future projects. I've tested it and it's working. Thanks a lot.